# Source functions are not loaded into current file

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2" src="aj.js">
```

I am calling function a() for my image onload event .but i am getting the error - function a() [a.js has function] is not defined.

How to resolve this issue

Comment: It might help if you provided the JS that was failing. (It might also help if you use HTML 4.01 and didn't use JS 1.2 when 1.5 is current and well supported)

Comment: Still its shows function is not defined

Comment: How are you setting a() as your onload event? Before or after the script tag you mention?

Comment: if your are down vote , Please add comment for reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a closing script tag. Also mime type is more important than the "language" attribute, which pretty much every browser ignores.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="aj.js"></script>
```

This, of course, assumes your `src` points to the right location.

Comment: Still its shows the same error